# Alamofire - best way of retry offline request

Tags: swift, alamofire

Here is what I need:

1. call post api
2. if success: do nothing
3. if failed(no internet available): put the request on to a stack
4. monitor if the network has come back
5. if network available: retry everything on that stack

even if the user close the app, I still need to have the stack available. I need to store the stack onto the disk

Here's what I plan to do:

1. have a class called apiRequest, it contains

   1. parameters
   2. url
2. have a class called apiRequestManager, it contains

   1. array of apiRequest

the apiRequest array is stored onto the disk. Every time, when user want to call the api, I call Alamofire.request first and if failed, put it onto the apiRequest array.

use NetworkReachabilityManager to listen if user can reach the server. If true, then retry everything in apiRequest. Everytime a request succeed, remove it from the array. else keep it as is.

The reason I ask this question is because I am new to the Alamofire framework. I don't know if this is a good way to go or if this case is already been handled in Alamofire.

Also, there is a RequestRetrier protocol. But I don't want to retry every single request again and again, I want to retry it all at the same time and if not succeed I do want to store the request on to the disk for future retry so I guess that is not what I want to use?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good solution for this?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I end up writing my own class that keep tracking what has not been sent. Just like what I wrote in my question on what I plan to do.

Comment: @nuynait Can you post a full example? I am also relatively new to Alamofire and iOS As well and was trying to make the same thing...

Comment: @denis_lor sorry I don't have time recently I am being very busy. I would happy to help any of your questions.